# Variable turns nill when a view changes

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

My ViewController - I am just selecting an image and then updating imageView. Still, whenever I am leaving the view, the ImageView is back to "face-unknown", because newImage is nill.

Why doesn't the variable newImage remember the image after the view changes?

```
var newImage: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if((newImage == nil)){
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"face-unknown")!
    }else{
        imageView.image = newImage
    }

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = resizeImage(possibleImage,newWidth: 150)
        newImage = resizeImage(possibleImage,newWidth: 150)
    } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = resizeImage(possibleImage,newWidth: 150)
        newImage = resizeImage(possibleImage,newWidth: 150)
    } else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "leaving the view".  If you create a new view controller when you return, it doesn't know what was stored in variables that belonged to the old controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your imageView is back to "face-unknown" because the `viewDidLoad()` method is called only once. Not because your UIImage is nil. Instead try to update your UIImageView in the `viewWillAppear()` method, it should works

Comment: Did that using override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool), but that did not work.

Comment: Can you check with the breakpoints if your delegate method `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) ` changes de name of your `newImage`  ?

Comment: It changes the value of `newImage`. I guess the answer is in @phillip-mills 's comment.